# What is allowed in Restricted XPaths (constraints)?

Tags: xml, xsd, restrictions, xmlspy

I need to apply constraints in a large XML file, like this:

```
<library>
    <book>
        <bookAuthor ID="1" nameAlias="PeerBR jr"/>
    </book>
    <book>
        <bookAuthor ID="1"/>
    </book>
</library>
<authorCatalogue>
    <author ID="1" name="PeerBr"/>
</authorCatalogue>
```

I need each bookAuthor's ID to refer to a valid author.

I am finding the "restricted XPath" very clumsy to work with, but maybe overlooking something. Am I right to define the constraint this way:

```
<xs:keyref name="bookAuthor" refer="author">
    <xs:selector xpath="library/book/bookauthor"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
</xs:keyref>        
<xs:key name="author">
    <xs:selector xpath="authorCatalogue/author"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@ID"/>
</xs:key>
```

It works, but my file is actually more nested, so it gets really messy. Plus I have to write a new constraint for "library/book/CoAuthor". Is there nothing more elegant I can do? Can't I abbreviate the selector?

Can I restrict the application of the constraint ("bookauthor[@nameAlias]")?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This question is not about general XPath expressions. From: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cIdentity-constraint_Definitions `{selector} specifies a restricted XPath ([XPath]) expression relative to instances of the element being declared.`. So, I've edit your tags. Plus, from http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#coss-identity-constraint it looks like you can use `|` node set union operator. So, maybe you could use `library/book/bookauthor | library/book/CoAuthor`, but I'm not XSchema expert...

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, you're perfectly right, I've read up the schema and tried the union operator the way you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer in O'Reilly's "XML Schema". It is ok to have:

- relative paths with child element
- namespaces
- all elements ("*")
- any child element (".//bookauthor" in my case will do the trick)

It is not ok to include anything fancy, such as:

- parent element
- tests ("[@nameAlias]", so no way to apply constraint only to  nodes with a nameAlias attribute)
- absolute paths

Hope this helps someone stumbling over the issue later.